# Showing the convergence of improper integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How to show the convergence of the improper integral:$$\int_{0}^{100}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}+x^3}}$$
According to my textbook this integral converges, but sadly there isn't any part of the procedure written. 
We could write this integral as $$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}+x^3}}+\int_{1}^{100}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}+x^3}}$$
I know that the second integral converges because $\int_{1}^{100}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}+x^3}}<\int_{1}^{100}{\frac{dx}{x^3}}$, and $\int_{1}^{100}{\frac{dx}{x^3}}$ converges (this fact probably isn't that helpful), but what about $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}+x^3}}$? How to prove that this integral converges?

Comment: Same idea, but with the term that dominates the growth of the function, when $x\to0$. If  it makes it clearer, do the change of variable $x=y^{12}$.

Comment: @NDB if I understood you correctly I get an integeral $\int_0^1{\frac{t^11}{t^4+2t^3+t^36}dt}$, but this doesn't simplify it a lot to be fair.

Comment: You can put braces around multi-character exponents, like `t^{36}`. Cancel some of the $t$ that cancel: $\frac{t^{8}}{2+t+t^{33}}$. When $t\to0$ this tends to $0$.

Comment: @NDB ok, thank you. Anyways I forgot to put them, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\left| \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}+x^3}} \right|
= \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}+x^3}} 
\le \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x}}
$$
These arise since the integrand is positive (as $x \in (0,1)$), and from making the denominator smaller by removing positive terms.

The integral that remains can be shown easily to converge from the definition.

Comment: It is not crucial but I would rather stay with $\sqrt[4]{x}$ as it is larger than $\sqrt[3]{x}$ in $(0,1].$